# Using activeX component in shared hosting

Tags: activex, hosting, shared

I have a shared hosting for asp classic, i am using an activeX dll in my asp script. ASP page works fine when i register the ActiveX component, i am using CreateObject function, but on live shared hosting i can't register my ActiveX component. Any idea how to use ActiveX component in shared hosting.

Comment: it is a zip utility http://www.xstandard.com/en/documentation/xzip/

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask them to install it at the server. Most probably they will not ;)